# Not able to upload code on CC2538dk board from Ubuntu 12.04 command line

Tags: c, embedded, rtos, texas-instruments, contiki

I have a CC2538dk board. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and cloned [Contiki repository](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/) from github. I was able to compile all the code in Contiki using `make TARGET=cc2538dk hello-world`, but I'm not able to upload the code to the CC2538dk board from command line.

The error I'm getting when I ran `make TARGET=cc2538dk hello-world.upload` is as below.

```
make: No rule to make target `hello-world.upload'.  Stop.
```

I used to use TI's Uniflash tool (CCS_Uniflash v2.2) to upload the the `.elf` binary, but it is not available in Contiki.

Comment: have you thought of reading the make file to see which rule are available?

Comment: the below is my make file iam not able to understand what is the problem                                                  CONTIKI_PROJECT = hello-world
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

#UIP_CONF_IPV6=1

CONTIKI = ../..
include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include                                          I even have Makefile.target where the target=CC2538

Comment: do a recursive grep of the tree for the name of this target and see if it's defined in any helper Makefile or anywhere.

Comment: After i performed grep on the helper makefile of CC2538 after i got this https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/cpu/cc2538/Makefile.cc2538

Comment: cld any one reply to this

Answer (score 0):

There is no make target for uploading to CC2538dk boards. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/platform/cc2538dk#software-to-program-the-nodes) one should use [TI's UniFlash](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CCS_UniFlash_Release_Notes_Latest#Installation_Instructions).

Comment: sir,iam finding it real hard to dump the code using TI's Uniflash.Iam not understanding what the fuss with new configurtion,old configuration and save path.We could not able to save the new configuration file which is showing that the uniflash is not able save at the specified path which starts with .TI/....

Answer (score 0):

I had success compiling the contiki examples on a separate computer, then using Code Compose Studio v 5.4 to import my binaries (ELF files) to an empty CC2538 project, then debug it from there in order to get it loaded onto the board. Definitely not ideal, but it works.

Setup:

1. Compile contiki source and examples from instantContiki
2. move the example directory, included blink.elf to windows machine with CCS 5.4 installed
3. make a new project in CCS, select Other Examples->Empty CC2538 Project
4. Import a C/C++ executable, then using the GNU Elf reader, select the blink.elf file you moved over
5. copy+paste the CC2538SF53.ccxml and the cx2538xf53_ccs.cmd to the new project, and try to debug using those configurations.

The reason this seems to work is that the xds100v3 drivers that come with the board's install disc and the uniflash tool don't seem to work right and just give me any number of errors. There's a black-magic-configuration-combination of the CCS 5.4 for Window's drivers/Other Example's CC2538SF53.ccxml that was the only way I was able to connect to the target.